# Derivative of big O symbol

Tags: calculus, derivatives, asymptotics

Let's only work with functions $f(x)$ that have a series expansion at $x=0$.
Is it true that:
$$
{d O(1)\over d x} = O(1)
$$
for all such functions $f(x)$? Here $O$ is the [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and we are expanding around the point $x=0$ (i.e. not around $x\to\infty$).

The only counter examples that I can find are of the type $f(x)=x^n\sin(1/x)$ where $n$ can be 0, 1, 2, ...., but these functions do not have a series expansion around $x=0$, so I am not interested in them.

Comment: What about $\sin(x^2)$?

Comment: @Jan: Very nice! Make it an answer?

Comment: $\sin(x^2)$ is infinitely differentiable at $x=0$ and the series is just a polynomial, so for it $O'(1) = O(1)$. You might be expanding around $x=\infty$, while I am asking about $x=0$. I clarified the question about this.

Comment: If $f(x) = \sum_k a_k x^k$ then $f(x) \in O(1)$ as $x \to 0$, and $f'(x) = \sum_k k a_k x^{k-1}$ so $f'(x) \in O(1)$ as $x \to 0$.  But this is more related to the fact that $f(x)$ has a series expansion at $0$ than it is to the fact that $f(x) \in O(1)$.

Comment: $f(x) = O(1)$ just means that $f(x)$ is bounded near $0$. So your question just becomes, "if $f(x)$ is bounded near $0$ and $f(x)$ is analytic at $0$, then is $f'(x)$ bounded near $0$?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question really boils down to what exactly you mean by "has a series expansion". As I noted in a comment, $O(1)$ at $0$ just means "bounded near $0$". Depending on how you define "has a series expansion", this may be true by definition. For instance, if you require that $f'(x)$ to exist and be continuous near $x=0$, then the result you want becomes trivially true (being continuous locally always implies being bounded locally, just by the $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definition of continuity).

There may be some issues with extended definitions of "having a series expansion," though (I'm not sure). For instance, I'm not sure what happens if you allow series expansions like $a_{1/2}x^{1/2} + a_{3/2}x^{3/2} + ...$.